# How to parse a .dat file and put it into a table in c#

Tags: c#

I have a .dat file that I want to put into a table that the user should be able to see it in the View. How can I accomplish that? The file looks like this:

```
�Control-Number���ESILAB-Redactions-Present���ESILAB-Redactions-List�
�kCura_0000004���Yes���kCura_0000004�
�kCura_0000006���Yes���kCura_0000006�
�kCura_0000010���Yes���kCura_0000010�
�kCura_0000029���Yes���kCura_0000029;kCura_0000031�
�kCura_0000034���Yes���kCura_0000034;kCura_0000036�
```

I'm very new to programming, so I would really appreciate if someone can tell me how to parse it and put it into a table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific part of the problem are you having trouble with? Loading the file? Reading the file? Parsing the text?

Comment: parsing and reading the file. What do the question marks represent?

Comment: What application did you use to open the file to read the contents? What text encoding has been used to write the file?

Comment: I used Atom to open the file. I don't know what text encoding has been used to write the file.

Comment: The question marks are present because your text editor is using a font or text encoding that doesn't support that character. You need to read the actual bytes to find out the actual character code that's being used. Or ask the person who wrote the file what character it is.

Comment: Looks like a binary file with some strings. You'll have to consult with someone at the source for more information. And as far as parsing goes, without knowing more about what the data is used for, it will amount to guesswork.